# Print list in ansible

Tags: list, ansible

I have a simple doubt. I am trying to print the data listed below :

user_list.yml

```
---
users:
  - username: alice
    uid: 10000
  - username: vincent
    uid: 10001
  - username: sandy
    uid: 20000
  - username: patrick
    uid: 20001
```

printusers.yml

```
---
- name: Print users
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - user_list.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Display users
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.username }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ users }}"
```

The above code does not work with the following errors 'list object' has no attribute 'username'. However, it works when i change the code as follows but it only display one username :

```
---
- name: Print users
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - user_list.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Display users
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item[0].username }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ users }}"
```

I tried several ways to print the entire username but to no avail. Would like to have some guide on how to print the entire username from user_list.yml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the `item` you will notice that it contains a single item with 4 dicts so the attribute `username` isn't found. Using `with_items` should work.

```yaml
- name: Display users
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.username }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ users }}"
```

To use loop you need to flatten it to one level as described in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items).

```yaml
- name: Display users
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.username }}"
  loop: "{{ users | flatten(1) }}"
```

*Note: When using `loop` here, do not put loop variable in a list. Below wouldn't work:*

```yaml
      loop: 
        - "{{ users | flatten(1) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked. But i am trying to get it to write with loop as per Redhat recommendation since ansible 2.5 to use loop instead of with_items.

Comment: Added a sample with `loop`. Beware of the `Note`.